# Is it possible to launch any action, script or automation when clang meets an include?

Tags: include, clang

the question is very simple.

My idea is to automate the inclusion of the required source files, in any IDE of choice, starting from the main source file and letting any parser (even one written by me, if necessary) traverse the requirements and therefore launch an action for any include found and positive.

I was wandering if it is possible to do with clang or any other tool.

Comment: To increase the chance of receiving good answers, I suggest you to provide a clear example and share with us what you have tried doing so far.

Comment: I've tried nothing because I don't know the features of clang. That's why I am asking.